# How to make search results are not showing in my table view from my search bar?

Tags: ios, swift

My goal is to have the search results from my working php search file to show up in my table view. There are no errors showing in my search view controller, but there definitely something missing and I can't figure it out. I have another .swift file as well. I am not sure where the problem is. Any suggestions?

```
 let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1/musicfiles/search.php")
var filteredData = [String]()
var isSearching = false
var search: [Search] = []
var filePath = "http://127.0.0.1/musicfiles/"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
    
   let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, snapshot, error) in
         

           let retrievedList = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                 print(retrievedList!)
                 self.parseSongs(data: retrievedList!)
                }
    task.resume()
            }

func parseSongs (data: String) {
  
    if (data.contains("*")) {
        let dataArray = (data as String).split(separator: "*").map(String.init)
        for item in dataArray {
            let itemData = item.split(separator: ",").map(String.init)
            let searchSong = Search(songname: itemData[0])
    search.append(searchSong!)
        
            for s in search {
            print(s.searchSongName())
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
   }


 }
      func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if isSearching {
        return filteredData.count
    }
    return filteredData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? DataCell {
        
        let text: String!
        
        if isSearching {
            text = filteredData[indexPath.row]
        } else {
        
            text = filteredData[indexPath.row]
        }
        cell.congigureCell(text: text)
        
        return cell
    
        
    } else {
        
        return UITableViewCell()
        
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    let searchSong = search[indexPath.row].searchSongName()
    let fileURLString = "\(filePath)\(searchSong)"
    print(fileURLString)

}
   func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
       if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
           
           isSearching = false
           
           view.endEditing(true)
           
           tableView.reloadData()
       } else {
           isSearching = true
           
           tableView.reloadData()
       }
```

}
}

Comment: You don't seem to actually search your data anywhere

Comment: I had a php file that searches

Comment: But you don't update `fiilteredData` in `textDidChange`

Comment: Is that the issue I update filtered data or should I replace filtered data with the URL?

Comment: You are displaying the same array filteredData for when is searching and when it's not. You need to filter the array with no filtered data based on the input from searchBar.

Comment: In cellForRowAt or textDidChange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to filter the data in `textDidChange`

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
   if searchText.isEmpty {
       isSearching = false
       view.endEditing(true)
       filteredData.removeAll()      
   } else {
       isSearching = true
       filteredData = search.filter{ $0.songname.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }
   }
   tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Then you have to change all data source methods to either show the `search` or the `filteredData` array.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return isSearching : search.count ? filteredData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DataCell           
    let song = isSearching ? search[indexPath.row] : filteredData[indexPath.row]
    cell.congigureCell(text: song.songname)
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let searchSong =  isSearching ? search[indexPath.row] : filteredData[indexPath.row]
    let fileURLString = "\(filePath)\(searchSong.songname)"
    print(fileURLString)

}
```

Note:

Optional binding (`if let cell`) in `cellForRow` is pointless. If there is a design mistake the code will crash and the issue can be fixed immediately.